# Advanced ordering of data.frame using multiple columns

Tags: r

```
#data as follows;
values <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1)
values2 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1)
values3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1)

Data <- data.frame(name = names, value = values, value2 = values2, value3 = values3)
Data[order(Data[,4], Data[,3], Data[,2]),] # basic ordering of data in base R
```

**Question 1.**

Is there a way to call something like `Data[order(Data[,4:2],),]` thus ordering all columns the same as the above code. (I have around 100 binary columns which I would like to use to order a `data.frame` consisting of 1600 rows and around 1620 columns so my code would look something like this `Data[order(Data[,21:1620],),])`

**Question 2.**

What if I wanted to have 'co-occurrences' ordered in a different configuration, consider;

```
smallData[order(smallData[,4], smallData[,3], smallData[,2]),]
```

Results:

```
   name value value2 value3
1  paul     1      0      0
3  dave     1      0      0
5  john     1      0      0
4  will     0      1      0
2  mark     1      1      0
6 steph     1      1      1
```

Instead I would like

```
   name value value2 value3
1  paul      1      0      0
3  dave      1      0      0
5  john      1      0      0
2  mark      1      1      0
6 steph      1      1      1
4  will      0      1      0
```

Comment: `names = c("paul", "dave", "john", "will", "mark", "steph")`

Comment: (`smallData <- Data`)

I cannot comprehend the logic of the ordering you want (under *Instead I would like*)

Comment: Sorry I have made mistake when entering the question. smallData = Data

Comment: The ordering will be used on synoptic tables of association where rows = species and columns = heirarchical groupings from a floristic classification. I find the co-occurrence of the names between the columns to have meaning and the original way that ordering works moves those co-occuring species to the bottom of the df..

Answer (score 3):

1) `dplyr`'s version of `base::order` is `arrange`, which is a little more flexible in what it takes, especially the SE version:

```
library(dplyr)
arrange_(Data, .dots = names(Data)[4:1])
#   names values values2 values3
# 1  john      1       0       0
# 2  mark      1       0       0
# 3  paul      1       0       0
# 4  will      0       1       0
# 5  dave      1       1       0
# 6 steph      1       1       1
```

2) You can arrange like this by inverting which direction you sort `values`:

```
arrange(Data, desc(values), values2)
#   names values values2 values3
# 1  paul      1       0       0
# 2  john      1       0       0
# 3  mark      1       0       0
# 4  dave      1       1       0
# 5 steph      1       1       1
# 6  will      0       1       0
```

Comment: You could also just do `do.call(order, list(y,x) )` in base R to retain flexibility of inputs, which means you can do `do.call(order, Data[2:4] )`

Comment: @thelatemail Oh, that's cool! TBH, I'm still a little fuzzy on what `do.call` actually _does_ beyond `do.call(rbind, ... )`. Off to the documentation I go...

Comment: Basically, `do.call(fun, list(a,b,c) )` generates `fun(a,b,c)` So, for the `rbind` example, you have a list of `data.frames` say, so you are calling `rbind(dflist[1], dflist[2], dflist[3])` when you do `do.call(rbind, dflist)`

Comment: I have tried on new data (adding extra name (row) and value column and slightly modified your answer to question 2. I wonder is it possible to use combination of desc(values) and then the column indexing from answer to question 1.    names <- c("paul", "mark", "dave", "will", "john", "steph","hope")
values <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0)
values2 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
values3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
values4 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
Data <- data.frame(name = names, value = values, value2 = values2, value3 = values3, value4=values4)
arrange(Data, desc(values), values4, values3, values2)

Comment: Actually yes, if you figure out SE `dplyr`: `arrange_(Data, ~desc(values), .dots = names(Data)[4:2])`

Comment: Thanks a million this works perfectly for the small example provided